# Typescript interface clone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

I declared an interface as below

```
interface Interface1 {
    property1: string;
    property2: string;
}
```

I have another interface `Interface2` which needs to be the same as Interface1. I could have used Interface1 where ever Interface2 is used.

But I wanted to know if there is a way to clone `Interface1` and assign it to `Interface2`

The way we do it for type declaration is as below.

```
type T1 = { property: 1 };
type T2 = T1;
```

I tried the below code.

```
interface Inteface2 extends Inteface1
```

The above line throws an error at the end of the line.

```
Parsing error: '{' expected .eslint
```

Is there a way to clone an interface and assign it to another interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Initialize the interface

You should initialize an empty interface with empty brackets `{}`.

Typescript interface clone syntax

```
interface Inteface2 extends Inteface1{}
```

Now, `Interface2` will have all the properties from `Interface1`.

Optionally you can add any properties to Interface2 in these brackets if needed.

```
interface Inteface2 extends Inteface1 {
  property3: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to att trailing `{}`

```
interface Inteface2 extends Interface1{}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJBGZBvAKGWOQAcoB7U6MAT2wC5kBnMKUAcwG4iTyqatAExNW7ENwIBfAgVCRYiFOkhYIQ5BAAekEABNmaDIpx4ZQA)